# Export Survey Results to Excel option not in Action Menu

Tags: 2010, excel, export, survey-list

I have a survey and all the needed results. I need to export the results to excel, though in the process of setting up the survey I changed or removed the Overview.aspx page/view. Now when I add a webpart like the overview.aspx, everything is the same except when I go to the Action button “Export to Excel” is not an option. How do I get that option back? If I can’t get that option on a webpart back how can I get the results of the survey exported to excel?

Comment: i tried it through the View All site contents method but still dont' the export to excel option, any ideas please?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem where the export option was not visible in the action menu. As workaround, I found that if I accessed the survey from Site Settings ==> View All Site Content ==> My Survey then the export button is available.

Answer (score 3):

None of the above should be necessary. The "Action" options are dependent on the view used. Open the "Overview" view, click "Actions" and the export option magically appears.
There's no way anyone would know this so this is a good example of the bad design / UX that plagues Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to do this either.

But I found one workaround:

To avoid having to open each response to see the selection made, I found that the RSS feed view at a least contained the value chosen.  From there I copied the feed into excel and cleaned it up.

I tried attaching the list in Ms Access - but it isn't an available list to choose.

If there isn't a way to get at the values in a response, I don't think I'll use this template again.

The above suggestion to find the export option didn't work for me either.

If you go the "rss feed" method, be sure you allow RSS for the list, pick your columns and adjust the item limits to meet your needs.  Find this under survey settings > communications > rss feed

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the overview screen and choose export to excel. A new window will pop up. Click on "show a graphical summary of responses" which should open the graphical response page with yellowish arrow tags click on the arrow shown in the picture and it should turn into a green check box[image] This should select all of your survey questions and auto format them for excel. All you have to do is click import at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: make sure to use the Internet Explore Browser the it works!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in my Sharepoint 2010.
I was harrasing Google to get me an answer but with no luck.
Then I decided I will create RSS feed out of the responses, and then the option to export to Excel appeared in my Action lists. Propably it gets the settings about the columns to export from RSS settings.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I added a new view to the survey results page and set it as the standard. Afterwards I deleted and the thereby also the standard view. After selecting "Overview" as the standard, the Export to Excel button reappeared

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution. http://danssharepointblog.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-create-export-to-excel-button.html

I will now follow this fellow's blog!